# Connecting to a ground pour in a multi-layer pcb in eagle

Tags: eaglecad

I need help to understand how to connect Vias properly on multi-layer PCBs.
I created a 4 layer PCB (Top - GND - V3.3 - Bottom)

Then I created a cutout area in the copper on all 4 layers around the crystal. Then created a copper fill area for a local ground on Layer 2 (GND plane). Now I want to connect on layer 1 to the local ground plane below the crystal with a via.

The copper pour on layer 2 is named GND:
[image]

But I don't get it done properly. I tried:

1. Adding a via on top layer, and naming it GND, but then it connects to the ground pour on the top layer.
2. Adding a via on the second layer, and tried to route a wire to that via, but also this does not work as the via is then circumvented.

The grey outline is the polygon I created as a local copper fill, for the ground plane below the crystal on Layer 2. As there is no connection made yet, it does not fill.

How do I connect from the load capacitor C17 to the local ground plan on Layer 2?

[image]

I also tried starting with a trace, adding via and switching trace to layer 2 (GND) but it still does not fill the pour when hitting the ratsnest button.

[image]

Comment: Did you attach a net name called GND to the copper fill?

Comment: Yep, the copper fill on Layer 2 is called GND
but so is the name of the copper fill on layer 1. Not sure if that works?
well currently it doesnt. Do i need to put the via on layer 1 and just call it GND? but then the airwire connects to layer 1 GND and not layer2

Comment: Try removing the copper cut out and instead of a copper fill make it a copper pour to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: You mean removing it on which layer?

Comment: On the layer that has the copper fill (to become a pour).

Comment: Did you press the button to redraw the fill?

Comment: Yep but the fill is not showing up (as nothing seems connected to it)

Comment: Have you tried a copper pour instead?

Comment: Apparently I got to admit, that I am kinda new to this still. What is the difference between a copper pour and a copper fill?

Comment: A pour will automatically attach thermal spokes to connections and avoid anything that it shouldn't connect to. A fill is a blanket fill and if it clashes with something then it creates design rule errors.

Comment: Hm i thought the gray outline I created is a copper pour, but it does not connect with the via. Do i need to call it differently than GND to make it unique compared to the GND layer on Layer 1?

Comment: There's a preference number associated with pours and you might need to ensure this pour is given a higher priority number. From memory I think it's called something like a Z number. Pours with a lower Z number take priority. Other than that I'm out of ideas.